# What does GWE stand for in rental apartment ads?

Tags: rental, accommodation

In rental apartment ads, you sometimes see the monthly rent listed with the added note of "incl. GWE" or "excl. GWE". Example:

> Spacious, luxury-finished and fully furnished apartment in Amsterdam
>   Nieuw-West.
>
> Rental price: 1,350
>   GWE/Inventory/Internet/TV: 250
>
> Deposit 1 month 
>   etc. etc.

This must be one of the additional fees/costs you need to pay, but what do the initials stand for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's:

- **G** - gas
- **W** - water
- **E** - electricity

which are some of the most common bills for utilities.

(thanks @audionuma for guessing water :-) ...)

Comment: *W*ater maybe  ?

Comment: @audionuma: That makes sense. Let's see if people upvote that combination...